# How to get the inverse of where ids => collection of ids in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to return the inverse of this statement:

```
scope :subscribed, lambda {|user| where(:venue_id => user.flagged_venues)}
```

`flagged_venues` returns an array of ids, so when I run that statement I get all of the flagged venues. What I actually want is the exact opposite: all the venues except for the flagged ones.

I tried it with `!=` instead of `=>` but that returned all the venues.

When it's changed to `where("venue_id <> ?", user.flagged_venues)` then I get this error: **PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record LINE 1: SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE (venue_id <> 2,4)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the ids that are not in the list of `flagged_venues`, so my guess is that you should replace

```
where(:venue_id => user.flagged_venues)
```

by

```
where("venue_id not in (?)", user.flagged_venues)
```